# C# How to merge the default case statement with one switch statement?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I work on a 4.5.2 .NET Framework solution with Visual Studio 2017
Here is my code:

```
case "medium":
    font1.Size = 14; 
    font1.RGBColor = Color.Black;
    font1.Bold = false;
    break;
default:
    font1.Size = 14; 
    font1.RGBColor = Color.Black;
    font1.Bold = false;
    break;
```

VS is telling me to merge the default case with the "medium" case
so I write this:

```
case "medium":
default:
    font1.Size = 14; 
    font1.RGBColor = Color.Black;
    font1.Bold = false;
    break;
```

but now VS is telling me to remove the empty "medium" case
so I write this:

```
default:
case "medium":
    font1.Size = 14; 
    font1.RGBColor = Color.Black;
    font1.Bold = false;
    break;
```

But again VS is telling to remove the empty "medium" case.
So how can I merge the default case with one existing?

Comment: I think it's saying, just remove the `case "medium"`. If you think it's clearer to keep it then keep it -- don't blindly listen to VS

Comment: Since `default:` means "this case is used for all values that doesn't have their own specific case" and if you remove the medium case, it will still end up in the default, since now medium doesn't have its own.

Comment: Note that it *may* be an indicator that you should be refactoring your code too. I can't say for sure about your code, but if you are getting unhandled values in your variable, should they be making your app throw an exception?

Comment: _"how can I merge the default case with one existing?"_ -- the most obvious answer is to do what VS tells you: eliminate the `case "medium"` altogether. It's not providing any _functionality_ in the code, which is why VS suggests removing it. If you don't like that, then just ignore the suggestion. It's not like you're being forced to remove it. _What_ to do here is really just a matter of opinion, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1:

Ignore VS. It isn't in charge, you are. If it is clearer to keep it: keep it. You can use various options to suppress the message to stop it messing up your nice clean build.

Option 2:

```cs
default: // note: includes "medium"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a direct answer to how to merge a case with the default case. This is more of a how to organize you code better to avoid this situation.

If the sample code is indeed real code that is part of your solution, perhaps organizing it a different way would make it easier to manage.

before the case statement give **font1** the **default** values

```
font1.Size = 14; 
font1.RGBColor = Color.Black;
font1.Bold = false;
```

then in the case statement leave off the **default** clause

```
case "medium":
    font1.Size = 14; 
    font1.RGBColor = Color.Black;
    font1.Bold = false;
    break;
```

the values will be the **default** if no **case** statement match

this way you dont run into warnings

also doing it this way, in certain situations, is superior to having a **default** case, for example imagine that "small" only needs to set the *Size* to *10* but keep the default *RGBColor* and *Bold*, doing it this way would not require setting those values in the **case** statement, those values could *fall through* from above